# Manipulate the values returned in a <xsl:copy-of/>

Tags: xml, xslt

Once again I'm trying to get to grips with the potential of XSLT. I've come across a situation where `<xsl:copy-of select=""/>` will suffice. As seen below:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="Instructors"/>
```

However, the XML is as follows:

```
<Instructors>
    <Lecturer>
        <First_Name>Jerry</First_Name>
        <Middle_Initial>R.</Middle_Initial>
        <Last_Name>Cain</Last_Name>
    </Lecturer>
    <Professor>
        <First_Name>Eric</First_Name>
        <Last_Name>Roberts</Last_Name>
    </Professor>
    <Professor>
        <First_Name>Mehran</First_Name>
        <Last_Name>Sahami</Last_Name>
    </Professor>
</Instructors>
```

The output is as follows:

```
Jerry R. Cain Eric Roberts Mehran Sahami
```

The output I would desire (and could accomplish with a template) would be:

```
Lecturer: Jerry R. Cain
Professor: Eric Roberts
Professor: Mehran Sahami
```

As you can see, there is actually more detailed information inside the "Instructors" node, yet when I use `<xsl:copy-of select="Instructors"/>` it outputs just the values of child nodes. I know this is the expected output but I was wondering if I can avoid making another template by manipulating `<xsl:copy-of select="Instructors"/>` to show some of the node names.

Thanks in advance and sorry for the fairly vague question.

Comment: Have you set the output method to "text" by any chance? I.e. `<xsl:output method="text" />`?

Comment: I haven't, nor would I know where to use such an element. Still getting to grips with XSLT foundations.

Comment: The output you claim is not what is in fact received: (a) your output is text, so you **must** have specified a text output method, and (b) you have spaces separating the values, where you should have returns (or nothing, if you have strip-space on).

Comment: The "Output" above is literally generated by using just `<xsl:copy-of select="Instructors"/>`. I have no instance of `<xsl:output method=""/>` in my code.

Comment: Which processor are you using?

Comment: I'm super new, but I think what you are asking is what I am using to process the XSLT? I'm opening it locally through Firefox.

Comment: That's not a good testing environment, if you want to learn XSLT. Try your code online, for example here: http://xsltransform.net/ or get yourself an XSLT processing application. Or do your transforms at the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using **xsl:copy-of**, use **xsl:apply-templates**. In this case, you can go straight to the children of the **Instructors** node

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Instructors/*"/>
```

Then you can have a template matching the children, which would be used

```
<xsl:template match="Instructors/*">
```

In this, you would output the text. For example, to get 'Lecturer' or 'Professor' you would do this:

```
 <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="text" />
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Instructors/*"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Instructors/*">
      <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
      <xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(First_Name, ' ', Last_Name)" />
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that **xsl:copy-of** should copy elements as well as text values. However, if the output method is text, only the text values will get output.

Comment: Thanks. If I had approached it with a template this is how I would have done it. However! I didn't know `name()` was a thing so learning has occured! Thanks Tim and thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering if I can avoid making another template by
>   manipulating `<xsl:copy-of select="Instructors"/>` to show some of the
>   node names.

No. XSLT is verbose. Just write the code.

Comment: Well it isn't like I was actually against it, I just thought I would see if there was another way around it. Thanks for the time. Like I said, it really does help.

Comment: @Aleski That's okay. your question is a legitimate one. But copy means copy - you can't pick and choose.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a slight change to Tim C's answer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>    

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Instructors/*"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Instructors/*">
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        <xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```